# GCC Error: extended registers have no high halves

Tags: c, gcc, gcc4.9

I am trying to compile a 64bit C library using `gcc-4.9.1.` While compiling with `-O2`, I am getting the following error at different places. `-O0` compilation works fine.

```
Error:
error: extended registers have no high halves
```

Any idea why this error message is coming and how to fix it. The line number it points to is the end of the function.

The compiler options are :

```
 -march=x86-64 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -m64 -Wno-pointer-sign
 -Wno-error=address -ggdb -gdwarf-2 -g2 -feliminate-unused-debug-types
```

Comment: sounds like a gcc bug. googling: https://sourceforge.net/p/covered/bugs/171/

Comment: Nobody should be using `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`, CFI directives do unwinding better.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this error has been added in this [patch](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2001-03/msg00471.html):

```
+   /* Irritantingly AMD extended registers use different naming convention
+      from the normal registers.  */
+   if (REX_INT_REG_P (x))
+   {
+       switch (code)
+     {
+     case 5:
+       error ("Extended registers have no high halves\n");
+       break;
+     case 1:
+       fprintf (file, "r%ib", REGNO (x) - FIRST_REX_INT_REG + 8);
+       break;
+     case 2:
+       fprintf (file, "r%iw", REGNO (x) - FIRST_REX_INT_REG + 8);
+       break;
+     case 4:
+       fprintf (file, "r%id", REGNO (x) - FIRST_REX_INT_REG + 8);
+       break;
+     case 8:
+       fprintf (file, "r%i", REGNO (x) - FIRST_REX_INT_REG + 8);
+       break;
+     default:
+       error ("Unsupported operand size for extended register.\n");
+       break;
+      }
+       return;
+   }
```

Try to recompile without the option `-march=x86-64`.

Comment: Doesn't that mean you should be using a different constraint mode?

Comment: Well, my first guess is that the default architecture will correct the problem by itself... but it is just a guess.